# delete records FROM google firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What is the appropriate code to delete records by Specific value from android studio .
Required: Delete all records If starCount field  equal 0.

```
private void deleteData(String strTitle){


}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to delete a node you need to know its full path. This means you you'll need to run a query to find the node with `starCount` equal to `0` and then delete each of them individually.

Something like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("starCount").equalTo(0);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            postSnapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Frank van Puffelen 100%.
How to update the (title field) condition (starCount =0 and body="d1")

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site which does your homework. Please do some research on Firebase Database