# how can to remove values in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How do I remove values in Google Firebase?

I want to remove values in Google Firebase, but I don't know how to do it with this code.

I'd tried the following method, but it didn't work:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications")
                                             .child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                                             .child("postid").child(postid)
                                             .removeValue();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code deletes the node at `/Notifications/$uid/postid/$postid`. Since there is no node at that exact path, the operation doesn't delete anything.

To delete the child nodes of `Notifications` where the `postid` matches a specific value, you'll need to:

1. Perform a query to find the matching node(s).
2. Then call `removeValue()` for each node.

In code that'd be something like:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("Notifications").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

Query query = ref.orderByChild("postid").equalTo(postid);

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            snapshot.getRef().removeValue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException();
    }
}
```

Also see:

- [deleting specific post in database(by post node) but it deletes entire database_table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52803390/deleting-specific-post-in-databaseby-post-node-but-it-deletes-entire-database/52803505#52803505)
- [Android Firebase: how to change objects with specific field value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203439/android-firebase-how-to-change-objects-with-specific-field-value/45204227#45204227)
- [delete records FROM google firebase realtime database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57551660/delete-records-from-google-firebase-realtime-database/57558947#57558947)

Comment: is it snapshot.getRef().removeValue(); ??
Because I cannot use getReference(), and still cannot remove notification values